# Considering more number of features reduces the efficiency?

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, feature-extraction

I 'm working on Handwritten Optical Character Recognition. Is it advisable to go for more features to get high accuracy of classification of characters Or considering few features will do?

Right now I'm using Gabor wavelets for Feature Extraction yielding some 250+ features and Neural Network as classifier. But there are lots of mis-classifications and recognition accuracy is badly low. So, suggest me some good Feature Selection technique or the number of features that I'm supposed to consider.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about machine learning theory / stats, and not programming related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the features that best represent your data. no more no less.

please give a read about feature selection:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_selection

http://jmlr.org/papers/v3/guyon03a.html